# Декораторы в Python. Декоратор класса, декорирование методов в классе

Tags: python, классы, декоратор

При изучении декораторов, столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Писал декоратор, который должен оборачивать все методы класса другим декоратором.
Получилось следующее:

```
def log_method(time_format: str, cls_name: str) -> Callable:
""" Декоратор. Выводит имена класса, метода, время запуска и время его работы."""

    def method_decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            formatted_time = ''.join('%' + sbl if sbl.isalpha() else sbl for sbl in time_format)
            print('- Запускается {}.{}. Дата и время запуска: {}'
                  .format(cls_name, func.__name__, datetime.now().strftime(formatted_time)))
            start = time.time()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time.time()
            print('- Завершение {}.{}, время работы = {}s'
                  .format(cls_name, func.__name__, round(end - start, 3)))
            return result
        return wrapped_func
    return method_decorator
```

Декоратор, который оборачивает методы класса:

```
def log_methods(time_format: str) -> Callable:
""" Декоратор. Применяет декоратор log_method ко всем методам класса. """

    def wrapped(cls):
        for i_method in dir(cls):
            if i_method.endswith('__') is False:
                method = getattr(cls, i_method)
                if callable(method):
                    decorated_method = log_method(time_format, cls.__name__)(method)
                    setattr(cls, i_method, decorated_method)
        return cls
     return wrapped
```

Тестовый класс:

```
@log_methods("b d Y - H:M:S")
class ExampleClass:
    def sum_1(self) -> int:
        print("sum 1")
        number = 100
        result = 0
        for _ in range(number + 1):
            result += sum([i_num ** 2 for i_num in range(10000)])
        return result

    def sum_2(self):
        print("sum 2")
        number = 200
        result = 0
        for _ in range(number + 1):
            result += sum([i_num ** 2 for i_num in range(10000)])
        return result
```

Пока все работает. И запуск команд:

```
my_obj = ExampleClass()
my_obj.sum_1()
my_obj.sum_2()
```

Выдает:

```
- Запускается ExampleClass.sum_1. Дата и время запуска: Jun 18 2021 - 15:18:41
sum 1
- Завершение ExampleClass.sum_1, время работы = 0.271s
- Запускается ExampleClass.sum_2. Дата и время запуска: Jun 18 2021 - 15:18:41
sum 2
- Завершение ExampleClass.sum_2, время работы = 0.52s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Но, если я оберну метод в классе через @classmethod (что логично для приведенного класса).

```
    ...
    @classmethod
    def sum_1(cls) -> int:
        print("sum 1")
        number = 100
        result = 0
        for _ in range(number + 1):
            result += sum([i_num ** 2 for i_num in range(10000)])
        return result
    ...
```

Я получу ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\LearningPython\example_14.py", line 63, in <module>
    my_obj.sum_1()
  File "E:\Projects\LearningPython\example_14.py", line 17, in wrapped_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sum_1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Моих знаний и понимания не хватает, чтобы исправить эту ошибку.
Почему теперь в метод sum_1 передаются два аргумента (видимо из-за декоратора classmethod, так и не нашел что он конкретно делает и возвращает)?
А, главное, как это исправить?

Код целиком: https://pastebin.com/8BmX69vi

Спасибо!

Comment: "Лишний" аргумент появляется из-за наложения декораторов, т.е. порядка их применения. В вашем случае декоратор `classmethod` необходимо применить сверху `log_method`: `decorated_method = classmethod(log_method(time_format, cls.__name__)(method))`.

Comment: Да и еще, представление в данном случае методов как классовых не кажется логичным, т.к. класс не содержит никаких ресурсов общих для всех экземпляров. Так как экземпляр класса вообще сам по себе пустой, методы лучше сделать статическими.

Comment: @user207200 Да, конечно, это просто пример.  Дело в том, что изначально я не знаю каким декоратором может быть завернут метод (методы могут быть разные). Явное декорирование не подойдет. При использовании `staticmethod` ошибка будет иная: `TypeError: sum_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`  Т.е., при недекорированных методах все работает, при `classmethod` ожидает один (я, так понимаю, что `cls`), передается два, при `staticmethod` ожидает 0, передается 1 аргументов.